# The Version History for a file in the library showing different "Modified By" Column

Tags: development, versioning, version-history

I am writing a tool to generate the versions of a file/page in the library. My Report should include the version number and the version created by/Modified by name.

While getting the modified by column for the version through code it is giving a username which is not same on the sharepoint UI.

This is the code im using to get the modified by value of a version

---

> SPFolder folder = file.ParentFolder;
>                       SPFileVersionCollection fileVersions = file.Versions;
>                       if (fileVersions.Count > 0)
>                       {
>                           foreach (SPFileVersion fileVersion in fileVersions)
>                           {
>                               if (fileVersion.Properties["vti_modifiedby"] != null)
>                               {
>                                   string author = Convert.ToString(fileVersion.Properties["vti_modifiedby"]);
>                                   Console.WriteLine("file version" + fileVersion.VersionLabel + " Author " + author);
>                               }

```
                    }
                }
```

---

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using fileVersion.Properties["display_urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Editor"].